# SQL Server : Query performance analysis - Any Optimization ideas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, sql-server-profiler

I have read multiple articles that recommends using SQL Server Profiler, so did I.

I have a quite important query which makes the application freeze from time to time. The query includes multiple `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... AND (... AND ...) OR (... AND ...)`.

I have no authority on the relational model that is being used, so I must work with it.

The query is about getting nearby hazardous products places in case of fire in order to help plan the fire fighters intervention plan. The query works, it only need some optimizations.

Now, I have this query had `6635 Reads`, `296 CPU`, `0 Writes`, `281 Duration`.

All I can come up with is that the query is too slow and probably too heavy for the server to perform. In other words, it's not optimal at all.

In case it matters, because I believe it does, the query has multiple calculations in its where clause like:

```
ATN2(SQRT(SIN(RADIANS(@latitude - CASE WHEN LocationType = @locationType THEN Buildings.Latitude ELSE Intersections.Latitude END) / 2 *...
```

I have no budget to buy tools or whatsoever.

> **UPDATE**

As per request, here's the monstrous query:

```
SELECT PHM.ID, HP.Name, PHMD.TL, PHMD.QTY
    , PHMD.CT, PHMD.C, PHMD.MU
    , HP.HR, HP.FR, HP.RR, HP.SR
    , PHMD.CP
    , A.HN, A.Alpha
    , CASE WHEN PHM.LT <> @7 THEN TL.D ELSE TL.D + ' ' + TL2.D END AS TLcol
    , C.D AS CD
FROM PHM 
    LEFT JOIN PHMD ON PHMD.ExID = PHM.ID 
    LEFT JOIN HP ON PHMD.HPID = HP.ID 
    LEFT JOIN BP ON PHM.LT=@5 
        AND BP.ID = PHM.BPID 
    LEFT JOIN A ON (PHM.LT=@4 
            AND A.ID = PHM.AID) 
        OR (PHM.LT=@5 
            AND BP.AID = A.ID) 
    LEFT JOIN I ON I.ID = PHM.IID  
    LEFT JOIN TL ON (PHM.LT<>@7 
            AND A.TLID = TL.ID) 
        OR (PHM.LT=@7 
            AND I.TLID1 = TL.ID)  
    LEFT JOIN TL AS TL2 ON PHM.LT=@7 
        AND I.TLID2 = TL2.ID 
    LEFT JOIN C ON TL.CID=C.ID 
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ExID 
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.ID = B.BID 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PHMD WHERE PHMD.ExID=PHM.ID)
    AND (((PHM.LT=@4 AND PHM.AID=@8)    
        OR (PHM.LT=@5 AND PHM.BPID IN (SELECT ID FROM BP WHERE AID=@8)) 
    OR (PHM.LT=@6 AND PHM.BID IN (SELECT BID FROM B WHERE ExID=@8))) 
     AND PHM.DV = (
            SELECT MAX(PHMLD.DV) 
                FROM PHM AS PHMLD 
                WHERE PHMLD.LT = PHM.LT 
                    AND ISNULL(PHMLD.AddressID,0) = ISNULL(PHM.AID,0) 
                    AND ISNULL(PHMLD.SuiteID,0) = ISNULL(PHM.SID,0) 
                    AND ISNULL(PHMLD.BPID,0) = ISNULL(PHM.BPID,0) 
                    AND ISNULL(PHMLD.IID,0)=ISNULL(PHM.IID,0) 
                    AND ISNULL(PHMLD.BID,0)=ISNULL(PHM.BID,0)) 
                    OR 6371010 * (2 * ATN2(
                            SQRT((SIN(RADIANS(@1 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LAT ELSE I.LAT END)/2) 
                                * SIN(RADIANS(@1 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LAT ELSE I.LAT END)/2) 
                                + COS(RADIANS(CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LAT ELSE I.LAT END)) 
                                * COS(RADIANS(@1)) 
                                * SIN(RADIANS(@2 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LNG ELSE I.LNG END)/2) 
                                * SIN(RADIANS(@2 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LNG ELSE I.LNG END)/2)))
                            , SQRT(1-(SIN(RADIANS(@1 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LAT ELSE I.LAT END)/2) 
                                * SIN(RADIANS(@1 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LAT ELSE I.LAT END)/2) 
                                + COS(RADIANS(CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LAT ELSE I.LAT END)) 
                                * COS(RADIANS(@1)) 
                                * SIN(RADIANS(@2 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LNG ELSE I.LNG END)/2) 
                                * SIN(RADIANS(@2 - CASE WHEN PHM.LT<>@6 THEN B.LNG ELSE I.LNG END)/2))))
                        ) <= @3)
```

> **`SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` UPDATE**

Please visit the following link for the execution showplan.
http://pastebin.com/k6GxxSKF

Thanks for you kind help! =)

Comment: Not sure if you're going to get much help on this as you are not really asking a question...you'll need to post the query if you suspect it's not optimal and need it optimized...not sure if I can give much help with this little info.  Left joining on Or statements is never fun...sometimes it's best to do two left joins on one set of criteria then the next instead of putting all the logic in the Or statement.

Comment: @Twelfth: I'm gonna update in a few seconds with the complete query.

Comment: @Twelfth: Just added the query to the question. Thanks for your kind eye! =)

Comment: No worries, was afraid the question would be skipped if we didn't add this.  The from statement looks pretty clean and the couple or statements shouldn't matter.  But that where clause containing several subselects is what I'd suspect is causing the longer runtime.  Unless there is a better answer provided below...I'd do some trial and error on this.  Run the query for a single PHM.ID in the where clause, then remove the entire 'exists' statement from the where clause and run again.  Compare the profiler results from the two runs and see how much change you see in removing that exists clause.

Comment: @Twelfth: When I do a COUNT(PHM.ID), it even takes longer to execute (550+ ms in duration). I got rid of the EXISTS() clause within the WHERE by doing an INNER JOIN on PHMD instead a LEFT JOIN, and require it exists later on.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller please post the XML output of the query plan here so we can view it in SQL management studio. Run the following `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON GO YOUR QUERY` then copy and paste the XML returned in the question. I can use this to view your query plan for anything that might help.

Comment: @Namphibian: I just updated with a link toward the execution plan. It seems to be the `LEFT JOIN` statements that cost that much.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I will have a look shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at query execution plan I can see that the most time is spent on the `LEFT OUTER` join.The query plan shows 73% of the query time/resources is spent on that one join.

Do you need the left outer join?

Most of the query is using index seeks and return very little rows which is as good as it gets. However they are using `NESTED LOOP` joins which is not the most efficient JOIN type. I suspect if you forced the use of the `MERGE` or even `HASH` join types you might see different performance. See [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) on how to force another type of `JOIN`. This is not really recommended though.

Are these tables frequently updated? Or are they very static? Also how much data are in these tables. I suspect that if SQL server is using the wrong JOIN type it might be that the statistics on the tables are out of date. Try running a `UPDATE STATISTICS` on the tables and check if the query plan changes.

Comment: +1 for pointing me how to get the XML execution plan and accepted answer for pointing me out how to analyze the execution plan so that the performance may increase.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller:  You can save the XML output into a .sqlplan file and then when you open that sqlplan file in SSMS it will give you a visual representation on the query execution plan which is a lot easier to read than the XML. One trick save the xml into a file as say file1.sqlplan close the file in SSMS then reopen it. Portable execution plans.